# Delimited List with Quotation Marks for SQL query

Tags: excel, quotation-marks, vba

I have a cheat sheet I use to for turning a list of orders in a comma delimited list. I've been asked to duplicate it, but instead of simply returning the values from the list, I've been asked to place them in quotation marks for a SQL query a coworker. So a list like:
A
B
C
Should be returned as "A","B","C". Below is the code I have for creating the CSV list.

```
Function csvRange(myRange As Range)
Dim csvRangeOutput
Dim entry As Variant
For Each entry In myRange
    If Not IsEmpty(entry.Value) Then
        csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & entry.Value & ","
    End If
Next
csvRange = Left(csvRangeOutput, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 1)
End Function
```

I'm totally new to VBA, but I tried playing with the code to figure it out myself. Adding more quotes, using the tilde symbol wasn't working. That basically exhausted my toolkit. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should be more explicit about where it's going wrong. We need more to go on than "Wasn't working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
If Not IsEmpty(entry.Value) Then
    csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & """" & entry.Value & """" & ","
End If
```

Comment: Thanks xelvis! This returned the value exactly. I ultimately fell on old tricks and made a macro based on a google search for how to place a value into quotation marks, then linked it to a button for my coworker. I wish I had looked up the rule for applying 4 quotation marks on each side earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chr(34) as a double quote.  Alternatively you can do a double, double quote ("") which is interpreted as a single double quote when done in a VBA string:

```
csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & chr(34) & entry.Value & chr(34) & ","
```

or

```
csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & """" & entry.Value & """" & ","
```